# how to reduce GIF resolution with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, animated-gif, uigraphicscontext

I have `Data` that contains an animated GIF and i wanted to know how to reduce it`s size before uploading it to the server. I am preferably looking for a pod that would do this but, i have looked everywhere on the internet and i couldn`t find anything. For a jpeg i usually use the function bellow after i create a uiimage from data:

```
    func scaleImage(image:UIImage, newWidth:CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    let scale = newWidth / image.size.width
    let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage!

}
```